# Proving a shift transformation theorem with taylor series

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion, transformation, mathematica, automated-theorem-proving

I need to prove a transformation theorem $T(ψ(x)) = (e^{hD})*ψ(x)$ and use Taylor series to do this task. It is known that $T(ψ(x)) = ψ(x + h)$ and $D$ is a derivatation.

I have no idea, how to start this issue. What function do I have to approximate to get this? I tried to do this with both sides of equations:

```
Series[f[x+h], {x, 0, 4}]
Series[f[x]*Exp[D[h, x]], {x, 0, 4}]
```

But it didn't work. 
I got output like this:
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekcdr.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwlV3.png)

You are my last hope :(

Comment: You might want to also try: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you please explain your terminology a bit more?  What exactly do you mean by "$D$ is a derivation"?  What are the domain and codomain of $\psi$? That is: is $\psi$ a function over $\Bbb R$? Over $\Bbb R^n$? Over a manifold?

Comment: In the script that i got from my uni it is said that D is d/dx and ψ is just a function over R. But i dont understand why it is hD and what does it mean exactly cause h is a constant so dh/dx would be 0

Comment: @Marta The definition of $hD$ is that $(hD)(\psi) = h \cdot D\psi = h \frac{d\psi}{dx}$. Does that help?

Comment: but the fact that it is exp(hD) and not just hD doesn't change anything?

Comment: @Marta It does change something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume (based on the context that you had previously decided to remove from the question) that $\psi: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, and $D$ is the operator $D(\psi) = \frac{d \psi}{dx}$.  With that said, note the following:

Using the Taylor series defintion of $e^{hD}$, we have
$$
e^{hD} \psi = \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}(hD)^k\right)\psi = 
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}h^k D^k\psi = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac 1{k!}\frac{d^k\psi}{dx^k} h^k
$$
Compare this to the Taylor series of $f(x+h)$ centered at $x$.

Alternatively: use Mathematica expand over $h$ rather than over $x$. In other words, use the following modifications to your commands

```
Series[f(x+h),{h,0,4}]
Series[f[x]*Exp[D[h,x]],{h,0,4}]
```